# ruby with jemalloc won't configure - homebrew/OSX/montery/m1/arm(?)

Tags: ruby, jemalloc

OSX/Monterey/M1/Arm/Homebrew: can't for the life of me get this to work:

```
./configure --with-jemalloc
```

It dies with

```
checking jemalloc/jemalloc.h presence... no
configure: error: jemalloc requested but not found
```

even though it's right there in: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jemalloc/5.2.1_1/include/jemalloc/jemalloc.js`.

`brew --prefix jemalloc` and `jemalloc-config --includedir` all looks correct.

I've tried various versions of:

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-jemalloc-include=$(brew --prefix jemalloc)/include
```

and/or

```
./configure --with-jemalloc-include=$(brew --prefix jemalloc)/include
```

but no dice.  Not even sure those env vars/flags are respected by ruby or if they're some rvm/rbenv/ruby-build thing.

I'm down to doing all my testing directly with ruby's configure and not a rvm/build tool.

Answer (score 2):

This worked using RVM:

```
# Install jemalloc first
brew install jemalloc

# Install using RVM:
rvm install 3.2.1 --with-jemalloc --with-cppflags="-I$(brew --prefix)/include" -E "LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix)/lib"
```

It seems that `--with-cppflags` works as expected, but it's being overwritten by the internal RVM flags passed in, so `--with-ldflags` does nothing. That's why we pass in the `-E` flag (as an enviroment variable) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
❯ export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)
❯ export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include"
❯ export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/lib"
❯ cd ruby-2.7.6 && ./configure --with-jemalloc
❯ make && make install
```

Comment: I tried this and it got much further, but I ran into:
In file included from ../../.././include/ruby/defines.h:79:
../../.././include/ruby/missing.h:33:11: fatal error: 'sys/time.h' file not found
# include <sys/time.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Thoughts?

Comment: Also, can you point to how you came up with this answer?